# Is there an online URL that can be used for ace script

Tags: ace-editor

Does the ace editor have an online URL to the ace scripts for specific use cases such as the following:

- A project always wants to use the latest version
- A project wants to use a specific previous version
- A project wants to test for bugs, features or regressions between versions (expects versioning online ace_1.0.0.js, ace_1.1.0.js, etc)
- A component was created to wrap the ace editor. The component author does not want to maintain a separate local branch of ace so he wants to point to an online source so his examples work out of the box.

For versioning example, I think [Google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions) provide a parameter but a file name also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple cdns hosting ace:

- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ace
- http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/ace
- https://unpkg.com/ace-builds@1.2.6/src/ https://unpkg.com/ace-builds/src/

gh pages https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js and https://rawgit.com/ work as well.